# The value for field 'Activated Date' must be empty

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am trying to migrate work items from one project to the other. Overall it works okay, my work items are being migrated. However, the state of the work items is not reflected. When, for example, the work item is closed in the original project - in the new project the same work item will be "new" and when I go to the work item there will be a message "The value for field 'Activated Date' must be empty."

I am using the latest version vsts-sync-migrator 11.12.7.0 and my query scope is broad "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')"

I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this message is only for those work items that were not in a "new" state in the original project - in the new project they will be "new" with "Activated Date" message added on the top. If the work item was "new" in the original project - in the new project it will be also "new" without this message (which is correct).

Comment: It looks like the default FieldValueMapConfig section does not work in my case. When I added the name of states in 1:1 mapping as follows: "Active": "Active", "Closed": "Closed" - it now reflects correctly the states after migration. Shouldn't the mapping be 1:1 when not specified?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below in your config file :
{
"$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
"WorkItemTypeName": "User Story",
"sourceFieldsAndValues": {
"System.State": "Active"
},
"targetFieldsAndValues": {
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate": null,
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy": null
}
},